# Merge Whisper c.db

Tags: data-transfer, app-data

Long story short I had to fully reformat my OnePlus One and when I restored Whisper from backup, the app no longer throws notifications to the status bar and the notification LED no longer lights on new activity.  Other apps work fine.

As a test, I uninstalled Whisper and re-installed it.  That time status bar notifications displayed.

Is there an easy way to merge an Android DB?  Some of the available SQL Lite tools don't list merging as a feature.

Comment: What do you mean by database?

Comment: /data/data/sh.whisper/databases/c.db

Comment: What do you mean by "**merge**" ?

Comment: I wish to take the stock DB and merge my DB into that one.  Hopefully keeping whatever throws status bar notifications that is somehow missing in my restored DB.

Comment: Ended up uninstalling Whisper then copying c.db from backup into the databases folder.  Now I get status bar notifications but the LED notifications still do not work.